# How to properly type React.Children and React.cloneElement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm cloning my react children with cloneElement but I'm having some problems to type them.

This is my code(it is just passing a custom onClick function as a prop to the children):

```
const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child =>
  React.cloneElement(child as ReactChild, {
    onClick: (e: React.FormEvent) =>
      childrenClickHandler(
        e,
        child.props.children,
        onItemClick && onItemClick(e),
      ),
  }),
);
```

And this is my `ReactChild` type:

```
export type ChildProps = {
  onClick?: (e?: React.ChangeEvent<{}>) => void;
  props: React.Props<ReactChild>;
  children: ReactElement | ReactElement[];
};
export type ReactChild = ReactElement<ChildProps> | ReactElement;
```

And typescript keeps saying that there is a problem with my `props` on `child.props.children`.

[image]

The message is:

> Property 'props' does not exist on type 'ReactNode'.   Property
>   'props' does not exist on type 'string'.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move/add the type to the argument of `map` callback since now it applies only to the first argument of `React.cloneElement`.

```
const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, (child: ReactChild) => // <- Here
  React.cloneElement(child, { // <- Assertion here can be omitted
    onClick: (e: React.FormEvent) =>
      childrenClickHandler(
        e,
        child.props.children,
        onItemClick && onItemClick(e),
      ),
  }),
);
```

Assertion has the same scope as the variable, so

```
React.Children.map(children, child => ...)
```

without type makes `child` type `any` (if you do not specify type of `children` somehow)

Then `child` is used as an argument and depending on the type of the function and your tsconfig it may require a value of some type

```
React.cloneElement(child, ...)
```

You put assertion here but it affects the usage of `child` as argument. 
Actually it is possible to put the same assertion to the second usage:

```
  React.cloneElement(child as ReactChild, {
    onClick: (e: React.FormEvent) =>
      childrenClickHandler(
        e,
        (child as ReactChild).props.children, // <- Here
        onItemClick && onItemClick(e),
      ),
  }),
```

But in this case it is better to specify the type of the variable where it is defined so it would have the same type in all its scope.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain more the reason to do this? I'm starting on Typescript.

Comment: @ncesar I've updated answer to give you some details

Answer (score 25):

The reason you're getting the message:

> Property 'props' does not exist on type 'ReactNode'. Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string'.

Is because a `ReactNode` can be either a component, an html element, or a plain string. Strings don't accept props. I've found that all you have to do to clear it is properly type guard for a valid React Element:

```
const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {newProp: 'myNewProp'})
    }

    return child;
});
```

Comment: This is perfect! I don't want to use any type and this check is really good

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
import {
  Children, cloneElement, FC, isValidElement, PropsWithChildren,
} from "react";

interface ChildProps {
  id: number;
}

interface InjectedProps {
  className?: string;
}

type MergedProps = ChildProps & InjectedProps;

const Child: FC<MergedProps> = ({ id, className }) => (
  <div className={className}>
    {`Child ${id}`}
  </div>
);

const Parent: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="parent">
    {Children.map(children, (child) => {
      if (isValidElement<ChildProps>(child)) {
        return cloneElement<MergedProps>(child, {
          className: "child",
        });
      }

      return child;
    })}
  </div>
);
```